# Dynamic nature of templates broken by custom handlebars helper

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I have this helper function:

```
// You can insert directly html from a controller, by doing:
//   {{rawHtml formattedName}}
//   where formattedName is the name of the controller property returning the html
Handlebars.registerHelper('rawHtml', function(propName) {
    var html = this.get(propName);
    if(typeof html === 'undefined') {
        console.error('rawHtml > propName=%s can not be found. Using empty string for html', propName);
        html = '';
    }
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(html);
});
```

Which I use this way in my template:

```
<td>{{#link-to controller.showRoute this}}{{rawHtml formattedName}}{{/link-to}}</td>
```

`formattedName` is a computed property:

```
SettingsApp.GenericModel = DS.Model.extend({

    'properties§name' : DS.attr('string'),

    formattedName: function () {
        var formattedName = this.get('properties§name') || SettingsApp.helpers.markText(config.lang.UNDEFINED_NAME, 'UNDEF');
        return formattedName;
    }.property('properties§name'),

    ...

});
```

This is working fine. But there is a problem: whenever the data in the store changes while the template is being displayed (no route change), the template does not update. In my application this happens whenever data is being pushed by the server (websockets) or whenever I trigger a manual / automatic store update (for testing) without changing routes.

I have narrowed the problem to the `rawHtml` helper: if I do the following:

```
<td>{{#link-to controller.showRoute this}}{{formattedName}}{{/link-to}}</td>
```

the template gets updated all-right. So, the store is working fine and the computed property is working fine.

I would like to know where is the problem in the `rawHtml` helper? What kind of update chain is it breaking? How can I fix it so that it does not break the dynamic nature of templates?

### EDIT

According to the [guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/writing-helpers/):

> If the name property on the current context changes, Ember.js will
>   automatically execute the helper again and update the DOM with the new
>   value.

But it does not seem to be the case: `formattedName` changes, but the helper is not called. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Tangentially related to your question: Are you familiar with the triple-brace syntax built-in to Handlebars? Like `{{{formattedName}}}` ?

Comment: Yes, I am, and I am probably going to start using it instead of `rawHtml` (not sure why I am using that, probably legacy reasons). But I still would like to understand why the update-chain is being broken by my helper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs (http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.html#method_registerBoundHelper) you should be using `Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper` to get this data binding.  `registerHelper` by default is unbound.